# how to create new column for median, mean and std in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, statistics

I have a pyspark dataframe as shown below:

```
+-----------+------------+
|       date|       count|
+-----------+------------+
| 2017-12-16|           2|
| 2017-12-16|           2|
| 2017-12-17|           2|
| 2017-12-17|           2|
| 2017-12-18|           1|
| 2017-12-19|           4|
| 2017-12-19|           4|
| 2017-12-19|           4|
| 2017-12-19|           4|
| 2017-12-20|           1|
+-----------+------------+
```

I would like to create new columns for median, mean, and standard deviation for column `count`.
expected outcome:

```
+-----------+-----------------+------+---+
|       date|       count|mean|median|std|
+-----------+------------+----+------+---+
| 2017-12-16|           2| 2.6|     2|1.2|
| 2017-12-16|           2| 2.6|     2|1.2|
| 2017-12-17|           2| 2.6|     2|1.2|
| 2017-12-17|           2| 2.6|     2|1.2|
| 2017-12-18|           1| 2.6|     2|1.2|
| 2017-12-19|           4| 2.6|     2|1.2|
| 2017-12-19|           4| 2.6|     2|1.2|
| 2017-12-19|           4| 2.6|     2|1.2|
| 2017-12-19|           4| 2.6|     2|1.2|
| 2017-12-20|           1| 2.6|     2|1.2|
+-----------+------------+----+------+---+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets try use window functions:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

k=Window.partitionBy().orderBy().rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize)#bounds you to column
md = F.expr('percentile_approx(count, 0.5)')#median expression
mx=F.expr('percentile(count, (0.5))')#median expression

df.withColumn("mean", F.avg('count').over(k)).withColumn("std", F.stddev(col('count')).over(k)).withColumn("median", mx.over(k)).show()

+----------+-----+------------------+------------------+------+
|      date|count|              mean|               std|median|
+----------+-----+------------------+------------------+------+
|2017-12-16|    2|2.6666666666666665|1.3228756555322951|   2.0|
|2017-12-16|    2|2.6666666666666665|1.3228756555322951|   2.0|
|2017-12-17|    2|2.6666666666666665|1.3228756555322951|   2.0|
|2017-12-18|    1|2.6666666666666665|1.3228756555322951|   2.0|
|2017-12-19|    4|2.6666666666666665|1.3228756555322951|   2.0|
|2017-12-19|    4|2.6666666666666665|1.3228756555322951|   2.0|
|2017-12-19|    4|2.6666666666666665|1.3228756555322951|   2.0|
|2017-12-19|    4|2.6666666666666665|1.3228756555322951|   2.0|
|2017-12-20|    1|2.6666666666666665|1.3228756555322951|   2.0|
+----------+-----+------------------+------------------+------+
```

Comment: Hi @wwnde  thank you fo having a look into it. I have a follow-up question. For some cases, the standard deviation results in `NaN`. Can you help with that?

Comment: probably here is just one row and while computing standard deviation, dividing by N-1 gives 0. Is there a way to replace NaN with the only/last value ?